# SQL query for more information in column

Tags: php, sql, json, sql-server, sqlsrv

I need some information about SQL query. Here my SQL table;

CustomData is column name in my table.
CustomData has more column.
It means columns in column.
If I use this query;

```
SELECT CustomData FROM Entities
```

Result;

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Telefon",
        "Value": "5417416039"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Adres",
        "Value": "AYDOĞAN MAH. 7.SOK. HACIHÜSEYİN APT. KAT:3 NO:6"
    }
]
```

I want to get Value in CustomData WHERE Name=Telefon

How can I do this?

### Edited

```
<?php

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');

  $serverName = "x.x.x.x"; //serverName\instanceName
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"hidden","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"hidden", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
  $consamba = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

  $sql3 = "SELECT CustomData FROM Entities WHERE EntityTypeId='1'";
  $result3 = sqlsrv_query($consamba,$sql3);
  $json = array();
  while($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result3,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $json[] = $row3;
  }
  echo json_encode($json);


 ?>
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database and version you are using.  Also, explain what the data type is for `CustomData`.  It looks like JSON.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Telefon's Value

Comment: @kalemteknoloji What is your SQL Server version? The data in `CustomData` is a valid JSON array, so you need to parse this data as JSON. Thanks.

Comment: SQL Express 2014 and how can i parse, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original answer (for SQL Server 2016+):**

The data in `CustomData` column seems to be a valid `JSON` array, so one possible approach is to parse this data using `OPENJSON()` and `JSON_VALUE()` (`JSON` support was introduced in SQL Server 2016). When you use `OPENJSON()` with default schema, the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, so you need to include additional `CROSS APPLY` operator to parse each item from the `JSON` array.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Entities (
   EntityTypeId varchar(1),
   CustomData nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Entities
   (EntityTypeId, CustomData)
VALUES ('1', N'[
    {
        "Name": "Telefon",
        "Value": "5417416039"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Adres",
        "Value": "AYDOĞAN MAH. 7.SOK. HACIHÜSEYİN APT. KAT:3 NO:6"
    }
]')
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');

$serverName = "x.x.x.x";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"hidden", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"hidden", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$consamba = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($consamba === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql3 = "
    SELECT
        e.CustomData,
        JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Value') AS Telefon
    FROM Entities e
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(e.CustomData) j
    WHERE
        EntityTypeId = '1' AND
        JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Name') = N'Telefon'
";
$result3 = sqlsrv_query($consamba, $sql3);
if ($result3 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$json = array();
while ($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = $row3["Telefon"];
}
echo json_encode($json);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($result3);
sqlsrv_close($consamba);
?>
```

**Update:**

SQL Server 2014 doesn't support `JSON`, so one possible approach is to parse the `JSON` data in the `PHP` part using `json_decode()`:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');

$serverName = "x.x.x.x";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"hidden", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"hidden", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$consamba = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($consamba === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql3 = "SELECT CustomData FROM Entities";
$result3 = sqlsrv_query($consamba, $sql3);
if ($result3 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$json = array();
while ($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $decoded = json_decode($row3["CustomData"], true);
    foreach($decoded as $item) {
        if ($item["Name"] == "Telefon") {
            $json[] = $item["Value"];
        }   
    }   
}
echo json_encode($json);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($result3);
sqlsrv_close($consamba);
?>
```

Comment: Error (sqlsrv_query): Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 195 [code] => 195 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name. ) )

Comment: @kalemteknoloji SQL Server doesn't support JSON. See updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
declare @entities table (id int, customdata nvarchar(max))
insert  into @entities(id,customdata)
values (1,'
[
    {
        "Name": "Telefon",
        "Value": "5417416039"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Adres",
        "Value": "AYDOĞAN MAH. 7.SOK. HACIHÜSEYİN APT. KAT:3 NO:6"
    }
]')

select e.id, c.Value Telefon
from @entities e
cross apply openjson(e.customdata) 
            with( 
                   Name nvarchar(200) '$.Name',
                   value nvarchar(200) '$.Value'
                 ) c
where c.name = N'Telefon'
```

Comment: please check my edit, because i did not understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CustomData

From Entities

Where CustomData LIKE '%Telefon%'
```

would get you pretty far